# How to create and to throw exceptions in Perl?

Tags: perl, exception

For example, php has exception like InvalidArgumentException with custom message 'Current group not found'.

And I can throw this exception in code.

```php
if ($groupId === 0) {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException('Current group not found');
}
```

I can inherit this exception and create another child exception.

How exception works in Perl?

Comment: You could use a `try-catch` block using [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try). Nice::Try also handles exception class, so you could catch an exception based on the exception class used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various ways of doing that, but they're not built into Perl directly.

The simplest one is to `die` and `eval {}` to catch it.

```perl
eval {
  die "in a fire";
};
if ($@) {
  print "something went wrong";
}
```

If you want `try`, again there are various options. The most common one is [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny).

```perl
use Try::Tiny;

try {
  die;
} catch {
  print $_;
};
```

If you want to be cutting edge, there's research done by Paul Evans to get an actual keyword `try` into the Perl code. He's released a prototype of this as [Syntax::Keyword::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax::Keyword::Try) and has given various talks about it recently, including at Fosdem in 2021.

Now for the actual exceptions, there are, as is typical of Perl, several ways of doing that.

`die` can take objects as its argument rather than just strings, so you can pretty much emulate the behaviour of other languages.

[Throwable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Throwable) is probably what I would go for today. You can easily create lots of these classes on the fly with [Throwable::Factory](https://metacpan.org/pod/Throwable::Factory).

```perl
use Throwable::Factory
  InvalidArgumentException => [qw( $id )];

sub foo {
  my $group_id = shift;
  unless ($group_id) {
    InvalidArgumentException->throw('Current group not found', id => $group_id);
  }
}
```

And later on to catch that, you can do:

```perl
use Try::Tiny;

try {
  foo(0);
} catch {
  warn $_;
};
```

Comment: Creating exception classes on the fly is fine, but what if I want to create all my exception classes in one place, and have them available throughout my code base? With Exception::Class, I can define exceptions as classes, and they're available everywhere once they've been loaded anywhere. I can't figure out how to do the same with Throwable::Factory.

Comment: @Dave can you ask a new question please? I'll answer it later today. Effectively you make a single class and use Exporter to make the ones you want available.

Comment: Thanks, asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69729489/best-practice-for-writing-exception-classes-in-modern-perl

Answer (score 0):

I like using JT Smith's [Ouch](https://metacpan.org/pod/Ouch) module, especially for web applications. This example is combining Ouch with TryTiny

```
use Ouch;
use Try::Tiny;
sub ProcessFiles {    die "Help, help, I'm being repressed";    }

sub DoLotsOfStuff {
    try {
        ProcessFiles();
    } catch {
        ouch 'That module/sub gave me an err', "died: $_";
    };
}
sub Driver {
    try {
        DoLotsOfStuff();
    } catch {
        if (hug($_)) {
            ouch 404, "Driver: $_"; # the caller wants a numeric code
        }
    }
}

try {
    Driver();
} catch {
    if (kiss(404,$_)) {
        ouch 404, "CallAPI: $_";
    }
}
```

Comment: If you pass option `:trytiny_var` while importing Ouch, you can avoid all the specific references to `$_` (e.g. in `hug` and `kiss`). Moreover, I'd stick to integer error codes for the first argument of `ouch`, although this is a matter of personal taste.